# Can Bing Map buttons and controls be customized and moved?

Tags: web-applications, bing-maps

When using Bing Maps in a web application, is it possible to customize the standard buttons/controls?

For example, moving all controls to the left instead of right. Or customizing a new look and feel for each button (different icons, etc).

The [V8 API Docs](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#overview) don't seem to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

There is minimal customization support for the built in buttons and controls. There are different navigation bars available. You can hide/show some buttons. If you want full control of the UI, hide all the built in buttons/controls and create custom HTML controls.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. And all of the built-in buttons/controls can be hidden? Do you know of any documentation or examples that show this?

Comment: Use the map options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712646.aspx Here is a sample: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#compactNavigationBar+JS